# Add Class mouseover/mouseleave to element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have small problem here,trying to make smooth animation,but when I mouseover element,then animation start,but if I leave this element to another element which is near that first,then that class jumped to new element and animation is stoped,because that first ele doesn't have that class.

I tried add *(mouseleave)="setSelected(11)"* but this doesn't work.

**Ts.**

```
selectedIndex = 0
  setSelected(id: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = id;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<span [ngClass]="{newClass: selectedIndex == 11}" (mouseover)="setSelected(11)" (mouseleave)="setSelected(11)" >f</span>

<span [ngClass]="{newClass: selectedIndex == 12}" (mouseover)="setSelected(12)" (mouseleave)="setSelected(12)">u</span>
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer. Try using blocks with ``` the line before and after code.

Comment: I made it with this solution, is not best, but working...
HTML
 <span (mouseover)="bounce(11)"  >f</span>
Ts.
bounce(id : number){     
      
      const myElement = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
      myElement[id].classList.add("newClass");
 }